# Is this valid EJB-QL?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejbql, ejb-2.x

I have the following construct in EJB-QL several EJB 2.1 finder methods:

```
SELECT distinct OBJECT(rd) FROM RequestDetail rd, DetailResponse dr 
      WHERE dr.updateReqResponseParentID is not null 
      and dr.updateReqResponseParentID = ?1 
      and rd.requestDetailID = dr.requestDetailID
      and rd.deleted is null and dr.deleted is null
```

IDEA's EJB-QL inspection flags the use of the two object `FROM RequestDetail rd, DetailResponse dr` with an inspection which says: `Several ranged variable declarations are not supported, use collection member declarations instead (e.g. IN(o.lineItems))`

The queries themselves function fine (as in return the expected results) on JBoss 4.2. Is IDEA all wet here, or is there a valid issue with the query? And what is the actual preferred alternative syntax for such a query?

Edit: Thanks for the help from all those who answered, especially Romain. I reported this as an [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-54589) to JetBrains.

Comment: What version of IDEA are you using ? - It looks like they did have some problems for this in the past, Cannot look right now there site is under maintenance.

Comment: @Romain, I'm using 9.0.2

Comment: Are there any other areas in your code where you do a join through EJB-QL ?

Comment: In that ejb.xml there are a couple dozen finders that use such joining defined, at least (on different classes in the ejb jar).

Comment: Do you not get the same error ?

Comment: @Romain, yes, I get the error on all of them. This was just a sample.

Comment: Do you get errors with other EJB-QL finders, and also which ones ?
The idea is to find commonality between the error cases.

Comment: To clarify my above question: If I understand correctly you only get errors on the ones with joins ? All Finders work correctly in JBOSS ?

Comment: @Romain, they all complain with the same error on the same part of the EJB-QL and all underline the From clause (with all its objects) - the fact that it has a comma delimited list of objects (two or three, depending on the query). All queries based on one object have no errors.

Comment: @Romain, yes the errors are only in IDEA, only with joins, and all the finders work correctly in JBOSS.

Comment: The obvious answer to your question at this point is that IDEA Code Inspector does not support joins in EJB-QL.

Comment: @Romain, indeed. My concern was that JBoss was being overly lenient and in fact it is not "correct" EJB-QL.

Comment: I looked at the EJB spec grammar and examples in the spec and I can assure you it is correct.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/products/ejb/docs.html

Comment: I added a cut and paste from section 11.2.5.3 Range Variable Declarations to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is fine - It looks like an IDEA Code Inspector issue.
I cannot find any bugs logged against it as such.

You might want to ask their support if you have the paid version.

I did find a minor issue, in the spec for EJB 2.1 (And all others for that matter) it says to use upper case for NULL.

11.2.6.10 Null Comparison Expressions
The syntax for the use of the comparison operator IS NULL in a conditional expression is as follows:
{single_valued_path_expression | input_parameter }IS [NOT ] NULL
A null comparison expression tests whether or not the single-valued path expression or input parameter is a NULL value.

```
SELECT distinct OBJECT(rd) FROM RequestDetail rd, DetailResponse dr 
      WHERE dr.updateReqResponseParentID IS NOT NULL 
      and dr.updateReqResponseParentID = ?1 
      and rd.requestDetailID = dr.requestDetailID
      and rd.deleted IS NULL and dr.deleted IS NULL
```

Here is a section from the EJB 2.1 spec that matches your queries...

11.2.5.3 Range Variable Declarations
The EJB QL syntax for declaring an identification variable as a range variable is similar to that of SQL; optionally, it uses the AS keyword.

range_variable_declaration ::= abstract_schema_name [AS ] identifier Objects or values that are related to an entity bean are typically obtained by navigation using path expressions. However, navigation does not reach all objects. Range variable declarations allow the Bean
Provider to designate a “root” for objects which may not be reachable by navigation.
If the Bean Provider wants to select values by comparing more than one instance of an entity bean abstract schema type, more than one identification variable ranging over the abstract schema type is needed in the FROM clause.

The following finder method query returns orders whose quantity is greater than the order quantity for John Smith. This example illustrates the use of two different identification variables in the FROM clause, both of the abstract schema type Order. The SELECT clause of this query determines that it is the orders with quantities larger than John Smith’s that are returned.

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT(o1)
FROM Order o1, Order o2
WHERE o1.quantity > o2.quantity AND
o2.customer.lastname = ‘Smith’ AND
o2.customer.firstname= ‘John’
```

Comment: Thanks, I doubt the null is an issue, but I'll try changing it to see if that makes the inspector smarter, but if it is valid EJB-QL, then I guess I will open an issue with them.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, but it should be noted that the null is not an issue, as 11.2.5.1 states that "Reserved identifiers are case insensitive." and above that NULL is included as an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming detailResponse is the name of an association-field whose value is a collection of instances of DetailResponse, you can this for navigation via the association fields:

```
  SELECT distinct OBJECT(rd) FROM RequestDetail rd IN (rd.detailResponse) dr WHERE
  dr.updateReqResponseParentID is not null and dr.updateReqResponseParentID = ?1 
  and rd.deleted id null and dr.deleted is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I would compare the queries against an official resource like [BNF Grammar of EJB QL](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/EJBQL5.html#68944) for J2EE 1.3 (since you mentioned EJB2.1)

For a more recent spec for JEE5 [Full Query Language Syntax](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html)